# Rails join with condition strange results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to build a query in irb for my rails project.

```
Test.joins(:server).where(server: { admin_user_id: 1})
```

which gives the following error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: server.admin_user_id: SELECT "tests".* FROM "tests" INNER JOIN "servers" ON "servers"."id" = "tests"."server_id" WHERE "server"."admin_user_id" = 1

This seems to be complaining about not being able to find the admin_user_id column in the servers table. Now the strange thing is if I sql into that exact database and run:

```
select * from servers where admin_user_id = 1;
```

it returns the row fine.

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error because the generated SQL refers to a table `server` that does not exist (its `servers`).

You can use @RSB's answer, or if you want to keep the same hash syntax:

```
Test.joins(:server).where(servers: { admin_user_id: 1})
```

See example in the [Active Record Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Test.joins(:server).where("servers.admin_user_id =?", 1)
```